# DependencyProperty to change value in the ViewModelClass (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

I have a UserControl which draws some lines where the coordinates (X1,X2,Y1,Y2) are bound to properties in the ViewModelClass, the ViewModelClass itself which handles the maths to draw the lines and the CodeBehind for the UserControl where you can set the value of a property which is needed in the ViewModelClass to draw the lines. The following code explains my Control and how it works:

UserControl.xaml

```
<Line x:Name="StartAngleLine" X1="{Binding Path=StartAngleX1}" X2="{Binding Path=StartAngleX2}" Y1="{Binding Path=StartAngleY1}" Y2="{Binding Path=StartAngleY2}" Stroke="Aqua" StrokeThickness="6"/>
```

UserControl.xaml.cs

```
public Constructor()
{
    private readonly ViewModel model = new ViewModel();
    DataContext = model;
}

public int StartAngle
{
    get { return model.StartAngle; }
    set { model.StartAngle = value; }
}
```

ViewModel.cs

```
public int StartAngle
{
    get
    {
        return startAngle;
    }

    set
    {
        if (value != startAngle)
        {
            if (value >= 0 && value <= 360)
            {
                startAngle = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
                StartAngleChanged();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"StartAngle", "Angle is out of range.");
            }
        }
    }
}

public double StartAngleX1
{
    get
    {
        startAngleX1 = centerX + (centerX1 * Math.Cos(StartAngle * (Math.PI / 180)));
        return startAngleX1;
    }
}

private void StartAngleChanged()
{
    NotifyPropertyChanged("StartAngleX1");
    NotifyPropertyChanged("StartAngleX2");
    NotifyPropertyChanged("StartAngleY1");
    NotifyPropertyChanged("StartAngleY2");
}
```

How can i set DependencyProperties (e.g. StartAngleProperty instead of StartAngle as shown in UserControl.xaml.cs) in my UserControl.xaml.cs and still make them change the Property in the ViewModelClass? Or is it better to leave things like they are in the CodeBehind and change the Properties in the ViewModelClass to DependencyProperties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare a dependency property in your UserControl like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty StartAngleX1Property =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "StartAngleX1",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(MyUserControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(0.0));

public double StartAngleX1
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(StartAngleX1Property); }
    set { SetValue(StartAngleX1Property, value); }
}
```

and bind to it in the UserControl's XAML like this:

```
<UserControl ... x:Name="self">
    ...
    <Line X1="{Binding StartAngleX1, ElementName=self}" .../>
    ...
</UserControl>
```

Then there is no need to have a private view model in your UserControl. You would instead bind the UserControl's properties when you use it, like

```
<mycontrol:MyUserControl StartAngleX1="{Binding SomeViewModelPropery}" ... />
```

Comment: I see that this is a possiblity, but isn't the reason to use a ViewModelClass to reduce the amount of code in the xaml.cs?

Comment: There are many reasons why you should have a view model. However, a UserControl should not have its own private view model instance. Instead it should operate on a view model that is inherited from its environment via the DataContext property, e.g. from a parent control or Page or Window.

Comment: You may of course have some login in the UserControl's code behind. E.g. the StartAngle property may also be a dependency property of the UserControl, and the control may react on value changes in a PropertyChangedCallback (that is passed by PropertyMetadata). It may then update values of its other properties.

Comment: As for the first comment, thanks for the tip, I didn't know that!

And for the second comment, I will get the properties to the xaml.cs and make StartAngle as a DependencyProperty. How would it look if the StartAngle would call its change to StartAngleX1, StartAngleX2 etc. with the PropertyChangedCallback?

Comment: VisualStudio dep tab that you can see the above.

Comment: See the [Property metadata for a custom dependency property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh920267#property_metadata) section in [Custom dependency properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh920267)