# Wpf usercontrol with embedded button : change button's content

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a simple usercontrol with a button in it which i modified.

When I add this usercontrol to my mainwindow, I can only access the usercontrol's properties. How can I access the button content ? Ideally I'd like to have a custom property let's say "TheText" and I changed it like that

```
<local:MyButtonControl TheText="My text here will be the button content">
```

This is what I have in the usercontrol "MyButtonControl"

```
public object TheText
        {
            get => (object)GetValue(_text);
            set => SetValue(_text, value);
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty _text =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(object), typeof(MyButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
```

But what Am I supposed to put for binding ? Can't figure it out. Here's the concerned button.

```
<Button x:Name="button" Content="{Binding  ???  }" Style="{StaticResource RoundedButton}"/>
```

Comment: "Ideally I'd like to have a custom property". Do exactly that. Declare a dependency property named TheText in your UserControl, and bind the Button's Content to that property. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44649504/1136211) for an example.

Comment: You don't need a new dependency property, just use the existing `Content` property of the USerControl and bind to that in your UserControl XAML. `<Button Content="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"`; in mainwindow, say `<local:MyButtonControl Content="Blah" />`

Comment: @Ed until there is another Button...

Comment: @Clemens It sounds to me like there's only the one button in the UserControl XAML: "the button".

Comment: @Ed Sure, right now it sounds like that. Still the general approach would be a custom property. And don't forget that you already have defined a UserControl's Content in its XAML

Comment: @Clemens It's called `MyButtonControl`. I think he's looking for `Content`. Maybe there'll be an `IconImage` property or something tomorrow but for now it's not at all nutty to use the content property of MyButtonControl for the Content of the Button in it. Plus there Content property is just sitting there anyway, waiting for intellisense to proffer it to some unsuspecting consumer.

Comment: OP: `Content="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" `

Comment: @ASh, I have edited my post. I am actually blocked at that binding place.. What Am I supposed to put there ?

Comment: @EdPlunkett thank you, your answer made it work ! How am I supposed to toggle the post as "Answered" if you only commented tho?

Comment: @user3673720 Clemens got it, you can mark his answer. He also has some good advice about related matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Binding should look like this:

```
<Button Content="{Binding Text,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" .../>
```

---

Note that a correct dependency property declaration would have to use the same name for both the dependency property and the CLR wrapper. There is also a convention to name the identifier field as `<PropertyName>Property`.

```
public object Text
{
    get => (object)GetValue(TextProperty);
    set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(object), typeof(MyButton));
```

You should certainly also use `string` as type of a property that is called `Text`. Or you call the property `ButtonContent` or something like that.